# Not able to locate the element with classname/xpath/Css selector in selenium python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

Not able to locate the element with classname/xpath/Css selector in selenium python. Please find below the code

***Create new account***

Comment: did you mean to attach code ?

Comment: Can you confirm the url?

Comment: It is a button "click" action has to be performed. Which will redirect to a Form